# How to extract angular velocities from navdata in ardrone_autonomy?

Tags: ros, extended-kalman-filter, ardrone-autonomy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We are trying to accomplish EKF slam using the A.R Drone. For the odometry data, we need to extract the linear velocities and the angular velocities from the **navdata** topic.
We have tried taking the navdata.rotZ option and subtracting subsequent values and dividing by the time difference. But it does not work. Is there any other way to get angular velocity from the ardrone_autonomy navdata package?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223925/how-to-extract-angular-velocities-from-navdata-in-ardrone_autonomy?/) by [Gautam Sridhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/25553/gautam-sridhar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-01-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you really need to take that information from the navdata topic instead of the IMU you could redefine the
navdata message so you can publish that information to the topic. The angular velocity is set in the same function (`void ARDroneDriver::PublishNavdata(const navdata_unpacked_t &navdata_raw, const ros::Time &navdata_receive_time`)
as the rest of the information but then published in different topics.

---

Originally posted by [JCUAV](https://answers.ros.org/users/24345/jcuav/) with karma: 41 on 2016-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0